# Sumar las pociones que me devuelve un for

Tags: php

Hola quisiera sumar las pociones que me devuelve el for, no es con count()

```
              if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                  $datos = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                  for ($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) { 

                      echo count($datos);
                  }
                }
            ?>
```

de hecho quiero sumar lo que me trae la variable $i.
es un carrito y no quenecesito saber son el total de los productos que esta agreagndo el usuario. saber el total de las pocisiones no sumar las posiciones. de 0,1,2,3, = 4 posiciones.

Comment: La variable i va a traer, 0,1,2,3,4 etc.. eso seguro no es lo que estas buscando. que es lo que queres sumar?

Comment: La variable de sesión 'carrito' que tiene adentro? Danos un ejemplo

Comment: Gracias por leer mi publicación. lo que necesito es contar el numero de posiciones y saber el total guardarlo en la varible.  0,1,2,3,4,5, = 6 es para saber el numero de productos de carritos que se agregaron al carrito.

Answer (score 0):

Yo creería que lo que estas haciendo es entrar en el array datos y sumar lo que contiene cada posicion, y lo haces con $datos[$i]. para eso debes crear una variable fuera del for y igualarla a 0, luego dentro del for pones:

```
Varnueva = Varnueva+$datos[$i];
```

Comment: Siempre se trata de esperar antes de suponer que quiso hacer el usuario y para eso se pregunta en los comentarios que aclare lo que quiso hacer, por favor mira [answer]